# What does GUID_SysMouse map to?

Tags: windows, directx

We have software that runs fine under a normal Windows installation but when we try running it under a hardened Windows OS with device drivers stripped out it crashes horribly on this call:

```
this.mouse = new Device(SystemGuid.Mouse)
```

underneath the hood `SystemGuid.Mouse` maps to `GUID_SysMouse`. If I knew what `GUID_SysMouse` was equal to I could figure out what device driver or registry value to put back.

**UPDATE**: I found out that `GUID_SysMouse` maps to `{6f1d2b60-d5a0-11cf-bfc7-444553540000}` but this key doesn't exist in the registry. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUID_SysMouse represents the system's mouse input device, which needs to exist for this call to work.

For details, see the [DirectInput Device documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204868%28VS.85%29.aspx).

It sounds like you may have removed one too many drivers - probably the one that your mouse input device is using, and made it invalid.  If DI can't attach to the mouse, you'll throw on that call.

Comment: How do I figure out what removed device driver is causing it to fail?

Comment: It will be a driver related to input devices - particularly one of the input devices that can be used as a mouse.  You must have some form of mouse input device in order to create a mouse device...